# how to make <iframe> responsive in wordpress. I can only make it responsive in either mobile or in desktop. need it to work well in both

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have used the following CSS and the html to make the iframe responsive but i can only manage to fix it for either desktop or for mobile devices, Please help me fix it for both. i would really appreciate your assistance

```
HTML 
<div class="schedule"><iframe src="http://pranamaya-yoga.com/calendar-2/action~month/exact_date~1477937700/cat_ids~156/request_format~json/" style=" border-width:0 " frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>

CSS
.schedule {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 153%;
    padding-top: 1441px;
    height: 150%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.schedule iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:-155px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry ben, I am not much of a coder myself and learning as it comes, I am using wordpress for the site. i dunno how can i submit the JSFIDDLE. If you can assist that would be great.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Vn8pmqAtU1 this is what you meant i guess.

Comment: Yes what amit posted works well with youtube video but for my link that is http://pranamaya-yoga.com/calendar-2/action~month/exact_date~1477937700/cat_ids~156/request_format~json/ it doent work well. I need the link above to be ifamed but at the same time be responsive to mobile and desktop or laptop. when view in different screed there is empty white space. The one that i posted as a question works well for mobile but in desktop it has big white space on the bottom. here is the link i am talking about http://pranamaya-yoga.com/schedule-thamel/

Answer (score 0):

```
    .schedule {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
     padding-top: 25px;
     height: 0;
    }
    .schedule iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    <div class="schedule">
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>  




.schedule iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: works well for the youtube video but for my link it doesn't work
http://pranamaya-yoga.com/calendar-2/action~month/exact_date~1477937700/cat_ids~156/request_format~json